# Cassandra Map collection type read latency

Tags: cassandra, nosql, performance-testing, database-performance, cassandra-3.0

I have a three-node Cassandra cluster with replication factor 3 and consistency level LOCAL_QUORUM. My table consists of two columns of `MAP<BLOB, BLOB>` type. Εach `map` contains up to 100 entries. I'm writing (append) into both maps and I'm reading from one (1R/1W per transaction).

After a few hours of writing and reading across 500k partitions, the table statistics were as follows:

```
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)                  
50%            10.00             35.43           2346.80              1597                60
75%            10.00             51.01           4055.27              2299                72
95%            12.00            105.78          17436.92              6866               215
98%            12.00            182.79          36157.19              6866               215
99%            12.00            454.83          52066.35              8239               215
Min             5.00              3.31            379.02               104                 3
Max            14.00         186563.16         322381.14              9887               310
```

So far, so good. The next step was to create 30 million new partitions.
After about 15 hours of writing (in random partitions) I noticed a massive TPS drop (about 2k):

```
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)                  
50%             2.00             51.01          20924.30              1916                50
75%             3.00             73.46          43388.63              1916                60
95%             4.00            126.93          89970.66              1916                60
98%             4.00            219.34         107964.79              2299                72
99%             4.00            379.02         129557.75              6866               179
Min             0.00              3.97             51.01               104                 3
Max             8.00         186563.16         322381.14              9887               310
```

Performing the first test again across 500k partitions, read latency remained high:

```
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)                  
50%             5.00             51.01          30130.99              1916                60
75%             6.00             73.46          62479.63              1916                60
95%             7.00            152.32         129557.75              1916                60
98%             8.00            263.21         155469.30              3311               103
99%             8.00            545.79         186563.16              6866               179
Min             3.00              3.97            454.83               104                 3
Max            10.00         107964.79         557074.61              9887               310
```

Read latency increases, even more, when workload involves writing a counter column(into another table):

```
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)                  
50%            10.00             42.51          62479.63              1916                50
75%            10.00             61.21         107964.79              1916                60
95%            12.00            105.78         186563.16              1916                60
98%            12.00            182.79         223875.79              3311               103
99%            12.00            379.02         268650.95              6866               179
Min             6.00              4.77            545.79               104                 3
Max            14.00         129557.75         557074.61              9887               310
```

What would be the probable causes? Could the `map` column type be the root cause? Any suggestions(configuration or schema changes)?

I am using prepared statements:

- **Fetch row by partition ID**

```sql
 SELECT id,attr,uids FROM user_profile WHERE id=:id
```

- **Update map entries**

```sql
UPDATE user_profile SET attr=attr+:attr, attr=attr-:attrstoremove, uids=uids+:newuserids, md=md+:metadata, md=md-:attrstoremove, up=:up WHERE id=:id
```

- **Increase counter**

```sql
UPDATE user_profile_counter SET cnt=cnt+:cnt WHERE cnt_id=:cnt_id AND id=:id;
```

This is my schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PROFILING.USER_PROFILE
(
    -- PARTITION KEY
    ID     TEXT,            -- PROFILE ID

    -- DATA
    ATTR   MAP<BLOB, BLOB>, --USER ATTRIBUTES
    MD     MAP<BLOB, BLOB>, --METADATA PER ATTRIBUTE
    UIDS   SET<TEXT>, 
    UP     TIMESTAMP,       --LAST_UPDATE

    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) WITH caching = {
   'keys' : 'ALL',
   'rows_per_partition' : '1' 
};

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PROFILES.USER_PROFILE_COUNTER
(
    -- PARTITION KEY
    ID TEXT,      -- PROFILE ID

    -- CLUSTERING KEY
    CNT_ID BLOB,  -- COUNTER ID

    -- DATA
    CNT COUNTER,  -- COUNTER VALUE

    PRIMARY KEY (ID, CNT_ID)
) WITH caching = {
    'keys' : 'ALL',
    'rows_per_partition' : '10' };
```

The data are encrypted. Here is a row sample(consisting of three map entries):

> YkceUdD6qEvOLw3Wgd8zWA |{0x95f56f594522:
> 0xacb7f42c7f0ac8187f17a8f2c04e5065, 0xa365a3dc007d:
> 0x24252727706b5065f9e1f65efec7ced8, 0xf0d55b110f87:
> 0x5a5ef3b0a041af8c7acf4040333afc96} |
> {0x95f56f594522:
> 0x000d31363333333334363636323639, 0xa365a3dc007d:
> 0x000d31363333333431323938363735, 0xf0d55b110f87:
> 0x000d31363333333431323938363735} |
> {'46TyNYCKTplibRyAfFsNRPQbvfQINNIIY4WmItuPayfvjDjEp49bnXSXLmD9hAm9'} |
> 2021-10-04 09:54:58.675000+0000

**Cluster info (per node)**

- Total memory 18GB(heap 5GB)
- 6 CPU cores

**Versions**

- Cassandra 3.11
- DataStax Java driver 4.11.3
- JDK 16

---

### Edit

After a few more tests, a high number of disk IOPS was observed, most of them read operations. More specifically, 20k IOPS and 1500MBps bandwidth were observed. I tried to reduce the number of SSTable touched by using the `LeveledCompactionStrategy` and lowering the `chunk_length_in_kb` parameter to 4KB but there was not much difference.

Note that SAN storage is used. I know it's an anti-pattern but unfortunately, we have no other option. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show query being run?

Comment: @Aaron I've edited my question.

Comment: Have you had a look at the disk I/O metrics (IOPS in particular)?  The partition sizes are good, and so is the query, so maybe the disk is slow?

Comment: Also, how many reads and writes per second are happening during this time?

Comment: Initially, while the database is empty, we have 4.5k TPS. As the database fills up, TPS drop to 1k. Each transaction performs one read and one write. Performing one read per transaction, TPS remain that low. I will check the disk metrics. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So to at least provide some theories before the weekend, let me just touch on a couple of things.

> JDK 16

So Cassandra 3.11 won't run on anything higher than JDK 8, so I'm guessing this is from the client side?

> Total memory 18GB(heap 5GB)

I suspect that the nodes would perform better with a larger heap.  On an 18GB instance, I would bump that up to somewhere around 8GB-10GB.  9GB will give you a happy 50% of RAM, so that might work well.

If the heap size ends up exceeding 8GB in size, I would go with G1GC (Cassandra 3 still defaults to CMS GC).  If you feel more comfortable staying on CMS, then I'd make the heap new size (Xmn) somewhere around 40% to 50% of the max (Xmx) and initial (Xms) sizes.

> three-node Cassandra cluster with replication factor 3

It's also quite possible that you need more than 3 nodes to handle this load.  The Cassandra nodes might be filling up with write backpressure, and dying a slow death.  After bumping the heap size, I'd try this next.

> Have you had a look at the disk I/O metrics (IOPS in particular)? The partition sizes are good, and so is the query, so maybe the disk is slow?

Not sure if you're running on shared infra or not (ex: OpenStack), but one thing I've run into in the past, was noisy neighbors.  You have instance that you're sharing compute or storage with, which is taking up all the bandwidth.  I'd check with your infrastructure team, and see if that's an issue.

Also, while working on that shared infra environment, I once ran into an issue where we found out that the storage scheduler had put all drives for one cluster on the same physical volume.  Hence, we didn't have any real hardware availability, plus the cluster's high write throughput was basically choking itself out.

Have a look at some of that, and see if you find anything.

**Edit 20211114**

Yes provisioning Cassandra’s drives on a SAN is going to be difficult to glean performance off of.  I can think of two things to try:

- Direct your commitlog to a different drive (hopefully a local, non-SAN) than the data.
- Provision each node’s data drive to a different SAN.

Comment: I've edited my questin. Have a look, please.

Comment: @Ikatiforis edit made.